# Sharing directories between multiple sites

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

We have a few different intranet sites for our various companies/divisions. A lot of the content is unique between them, but they do have some shared components.

Our current deployment setup (which sucks) involves using the Copy Web Site tool in Visual Studio to copy/sync files between the project directory and the deployment location on the server. Then in IIS on the server, we can set up virtual directories pointing to the shared items (mostly .aspx pages). These pages look for a standard master page in the root of the site, and thus work fine in each separate site with its respective branding.

A few examples:

- /VacationCalendar
- /PhoneDir
- /Controls (.ascx files)

While it works okay in production, it sucks for a number of reasons:

- The Copy Web Site tool sucks.
- You can't debug these components locally, since they don't actually exist in the site.
- The site isn't precompiled, which brings obvious performance issues.

So I'd like to throw out all that nonsense and switch to using precompiled sites, with a Web Deployment project putting everything in place on the server. This raises the problem of what to do about the shared components. I'm pretty sure I can't get away with the virtual directory trick in this kind of environment, and frankly, I don't really want to.

How do I make a subdirectory of .aspx/.ascx files and associated image/script/CSS resources act sort of like a class library? Suppose I put everything that's in the VacationCalendar directory into its own project/solution, then have each intranet site import that and make all those files available under the /VacationCalendar path. Is there some way to do anything like that without major headaches?

I don't really want to merge all these sites into a single solution, as there's always a possibility of needing to restrict access in source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer - I didn't try this out.

Create your shared directories as subdirectories in their own projects.  Deploy those projects to a webserver under a disabled site, but link to the actual subdirectory there from the live site.

So in IIS you could have

```
+ - DisabledWebsite
|   |
|   + --- PhoneProject
|         |
|         + --- PhoneDir (at c:/webs/PhoneProject/PhoneDir
|
+ - EnabledSite
    |
    + --- RealProject (bound to http:something.com for example)
          |
          +-- PhoneDir (virtual linked to c:/webs/PhoneProject/PhoneDir
```

You could then compile PhoneProject and deploy it separately from RealProject.  You would probably also have to have a separate namespace for PhoneProject and put its compiled dll into the RealProject/bin directory.

Comment: That's roughly what we're doing now, and I've even seen it suggested in a Microsoft KB article, so I'm guessing this is the only sane way to do it. As a followup question, is there a way to use Web Deployment Projects in such a way that this can still work? I really loathe the Copy Web Site tool, and hope to get away from it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that not obvious or my idea sucks. Anyway:

Make a Master Page, link all sites (precompiled) and have:

- Upload on each site that saves in some specific directory (for that site only)
- Global Upload on Master Page that saves all files in same dir (available to everyone)

Master Page can have a dir for all shared resources, and each site can have a different folder. No confusion. You can even demand login for some dirs, and set privileges